# prevent favicon.ico from downloading

Tags: android, html, url, picasso, favicon

I want to view `favicon.ico` in the browser but not download them to my computer. How do I enforce that?

**punch line**

I have an app that is supposed to display favicons given a url. The app is successful only when the `favicon.ico` would display in browser as opposed to downloading. So I need to somehow force the image to display in browser. For example `http://www.nydailynews.com/favicon.ico` does not display in browser but rather downloads (chrome browser). But I see that safari is able to force it to display in browser. How can my android app do the same, as safari?

From android I am using picasso to load the images in a ListView

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Favicon does load in the `WebView`, it doesn't download it. I just tried the following code,

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/favicon.ico");
```

And this loads the icon in the `WebView`. Also I tried opening the same url in my `Chrome Android` app and it works too. It doesn't download it.
P.S. Note that I'm testing on Motorola Moto X running Android 5.1.

**Update**

Try this

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\"http://www.nydailynews.com/favicon.ico\"/></body>";
webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Ok, this is strange! The above url doesn't work but Google works, and also my personal website works. Hmm...Thinking...

Comment: That's the very point of my question: some work and some don't. But even the ones that do not work, actually do work in the Safari browser. So Safari must be doing something. And I am wondering if android or picasso can do that same something. But thanks for trying to help, I was sure this question had too many parts to get help (favicon and android is a rare combination). So thanks.

Comment: I am not not using a webview. I am using a ListView with Picasso (see the Picasso hashtag). But perhaps picasso can work this this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the `picasso` tag altogether. But when I try the following code, it works for me. `ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://www.nydailynews.com/favicon.ico").into(image);` Am not sure, whats going with your `ListView` then.

Comment: All the ones that load in chrome load for me; the ones that would not load in chrome don't load in my ListView either. I am using galaxy s5. So maybe there is a thing there.